# Parton model and impulse approximation for the process $2\to 1$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

Consider a process 
$$
\tag 1 N+N\to X+\text{all},
$$
where $N$ are nucleons and $X$ is some massive particle. Assuming the parton model is valid and there is vertex $PP'X$, where $P,P'$ are partons inside the nucleons, the process $(1)$ can be described as the $2 \to 1$ Drell-Yan like process
$$
\tag 2 P+P'\to X
$$
Following [Drell and Yan](http://inspirehep.net/record/60911), let's assume that the parton model is applicable if the lifetime of the virtual state with the partons inside the nucleon is much larger than the time of the interaction $(2)$,
$$
\tag 3 t_{\text{lifetime}}\gg t_{\text{int}}
$$
If it holds, parton can be assumed as free particle carrying amount $x$ of the nucleon momentum, and probabilistic interpretation of the process $(2)$ becomes valid (this approximation is known as impulse approximation).

Assuming that nucleons have sufficiently large momenta $|\mathbf p|$ at their CM frame, $t_{\text{lifetime}}$ can be estimated as (using time-energy uncertainty principle)
$$
\tag 4 t_{\text{lifetime}} \simeq 2|\mathbf p|/m_{N}^{2}
$$
As for the interaction time, naively I think that it can be estimated using Fermi Golden rule,
$$
\tag 5 t_{\text{int}}^{-1}\simeq \frac{1}{V}\frac{1}{2E_{P}2E_{P'}}\int |M_{\text{hard}}|^{2}\delta(p_{X} - p_{P}-p_{P'})\frac{d^{3}\mathbf p_{X}}{(2\pi)^{3}2E_{X}},
$$
where $V\simeq m_{N}^{-3}\gamma_{N}^{-3}$ is the proper volume of the nucleon and $M_{\text{hard}}$ is the matrix element of the process $(2)$.

Assuming that this is correct, the validity criterion $(3)$ depends on the mass of $X$ particle and on its coupling to partons. However, in the literature (see [this overview article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0051.pdf) for example, expression $(33)$ and corresponding discussion) the criterion $(3)$ is replaced by very simple relation 
$$
\tag 6 s_{PP'} \gg \Lambda_{\text{QCD}}^{2},
$$ 
where $s_{PP'} = m_{X}^{2}$ is partonic invariant mass. Therefore we replaced probability criterion by more special QCD perturbativity criterion.

**My question is the following.** Whereas $(3)$ is model dependent criterion (it depends on the type of nucleon, the coupling of $X$ to partons and $X$ mass, as is demonstrated by $(5)$-$(6)$), $(6)$ depends only on $X$ mass. I don't clearly understand why it is reasonable to replace $(3)$ by $(6)$, since naively $(3)$ can be violated while $(6)$ holds, and vice versa. Could you please comment on that?

P.S. In principle, my question is related to general process $2\to n$, but for clarity let's concentrate on $2 \to 1$ process.

Comment: Few comments since no reply yet: For DIS, the energy of the probe in the nucleon rest frame is $q^0 \sim Q^2/2xm_N$. The reciprocal of that is representative of the timescale of scattering event which need be $\gg$ than the typical partonic interaction time $\sim 1/m_N$ for justification of parton model. So we get the equalities $\tau_{scattering} \sim 1/q^0 \gg \tau_{int} \sim 1/m_N$ which is also implied if $q^0 \gg m_N \sim \Lambda_{QCD}$, not dissimilar to the 'perturbativity' condition you mention at the close of your post.

Comment: @CAF : thank you for the answer; however, some aspects are not clear for me. First of all, what is $x$ in nucleon rest frame? Then, how to obtain the expression for $q_{0}$? And also why the scattering time is related to $q_{0}$ by the relation $\tau_{\text{scattering}} \sim q^{-1}_{0}$? Assuming that this is due to uncertainty principle, $q_{0}$ has to be the energy of the excited state, while I don't clearly understand why it is so.

Comment: In the IMF frame of the proton, $x$ has the interpretation of momentum fraction carried by the struck parton. $x$ is written in terms of Lorentz invariants, e.g in DIS $x=Q^2/2P\cdot q$ but I think in rest frame of proton this interpretation simply no longer holds. In proton rest frame, $P^{\mu} = (m_P, 0,0,0)$ with $q^{\mu} = (q^0, 0,0,q_z)$ e.g. then the product $P \cdot q = m_P q^0$ so that $q^0 = P \cdot q/m_P$. Use the expression for $x$ as given above gives the result. Yes, it's all order of magnitude estimates via uncertainty principle using characteristic scales in the problem.